# there exists a $u \in L^\infty(X)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{X} u_nv = \int_{X} uv \space\space \forall v \in L^1(X)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^\infty(X)$ and assume that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{X} u_nv$ exists $ \forall v \in L^1(X)$. Then there exists a $u \in L^\infty(X)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{X} u_nv = \int_{X} uv  \space\space \forall v \in L^1(X)$.

My thought: Since the integral can be viewed (By Riesz Representation) as a sequence of $T_n(v) = \int_{X} u_nv$. The hypothesis shows that $T_n$ is convergent. This is the condition of Banach-Saks-Steinhaus Theorem (Royden 13.5). The operator given in this theorem $T = lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is linear and continuous hence again in the dual space. By Riesz Representation Theorem T is of the form $T(v) = \int_{X} uv$ for some $u \in L^\infty(X) $.

(Sorry for many unclarity, I am a Latex beginner).

Comment: Your proof if fine.

Comment: Why do you think the norm is bounded? Also what is your question?